# Getting undefined behavior for something that shouldn't be getting undefined behavior

Tags: c++

```
class Sample
{
public:
    int *ptr;

    Sample(int i)
    {
      ptr = new int(i);
    }
    ~Sample()
    {
      delete ptr;
    }
    void PrintVal()
    {
      cout << "The value is " << *ptr;
    }
};
  void SomeFunc(Sample x)
  {
    cout << "Say i am in someFunc " << endl;
  }
  int main()
  {
    Sample s1 = new Sample(10);
    SomeFunc(s1);
    s1.PrintVal();
  }
```

Two things that I think should happen:

1. `s1` can be initialized using the parameterised constructor.
2. The value of `*ptr` from PrintVal() should be 10.

For 1) I'm getting `invalid conversion from 'Sample*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]`. I'm calling the constructor properly, why is this happening?
For the case of 2) I'm getting either a garbage value or the program gets an segmentation fault. This shouldn't happen because the `ptr` of the local object `x` of the SomeFunc should be deleted not the `ptr` of `s1` as it is passed by value not reference. IIRC pass by value for objects sends a copy of the object to the function's receiving arguments.

Comment: I can't see how this compiles, but you definitely need a copy constructor and an assignment operator - see rule of 3.

Comment: C++ is not Java, there is a difference btw pointer and object.

Comment: `Sample *s1 = new Sample(10);`

Comment: (1) `new Sample(10)` creates a new `Sample` and returns a pointer to it. You then use that pointer to initialize `Sample s1`, so it tries to use the `Sample(int)` constructor. But it can't convert the `Sample*` to an `int`. (2) You copy the `Sample` to pass it to `SomeFunc`. The default copy constructor copies the members, which means that when the `SomeFunc` destructs its parameter `x`, the pointer is freed, leaving the pointer in `s1` pointing to garbage.

Comment: You need to follow the [rule of 3-5-0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). When you copy your object, two instances now own the same dynamically allocated `int` and both try to destroy it.

Comment: If you have undefined behavior and you don't expect undefined behavior, then your assumption that your code has no undefined behavior will almost always be incorrect.

Comment: Note that when you `delete ptr;` you delete the *pointed object*, not the pointer. If you copy a pointer you now have two pointers to the same object. It's not correct to delete that object twice.

Comment: It's time to hit the books again I guess, I haven't used C++ in a while and have been focusing on Java a bit too much maybe that's why I'm getting stuck like this. Thank you for all responses.

Comment: The code has diagnosable errors, so will not compile or be executed.   If you fix it so it compiles then, yes, it will have undefined behaviour.   To fix that, look up "rule of three" in the first instance.   Your subject line is meaningless - there is no such thing as "getting undefined behavior for something that shouldn't be getting undefined behavior" - behaviour is either undefined or it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code *does* have undefined behaviour. But let’s start at the beginning.

```
Sample s1 = new Sample(10);
```

This is what happens in this line:

1. A `Sample` object is allocated on the heap and the `new` expression returns a pointer to it, a `Sample*`.
2. You cannot assign a `Sample*` to a variable of type `Sample`. But `Sample` has a constructor that allows implicit construction from an int. If you use the `-fpermissive` compiler option (hint: don’t!), the compiler allows implicit conversion of a pointer to an integer – after all, a pointer is just a memory address, a.k.a. a number.
3. Accordingly `s1` is constructed by interpreting the memory address of the heap `Sample` object as an integer (truncating it if `sizeof(Sample*) > sizeof(int)`). That’s the value that ends up as `*(s1.ptr)`.

To reiterate the key point: In that line you don’t instantiate one `Sample` object, but two. **Bug 1**: The one created on the heap is never deleted. That’s a memory leak.

```
SomeFunc(s1);
```

`Sample` has nothing in it that prevents the compiler from generating the default copy constructor and default copy assignment operator. Important: “default” for pointers means to copy the pointer, not the object behind it. So:

1. `s1` is copied to call `SomeFunc()`. The copy is available as `x` in the function. Because of the default pointer copy both `s1` and `x` point to the same `int` object.
2. `x` goes out of scope at the end of the function, the destructor runs and deletes the `int` object.

We are not *quite* undefined yet, but we’re getting close.

```
s1.PrintVal();
```

The function tries to acces the `int` object behind the pointer, but it’s already deleted. `s1.ptr` is a dangling pointer. **Bug 2**: Dereferencing a dangling pointer is undefined behaviour.

And all that because of that seemingly innocent implicit pointer-to-int conversion … That’s why it is a compiler error by default, at least in non-ancient compilers.